# CTE cycle error in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5f3b40/1

I have a tabel `del`

```
 CMPI_CODE CMPI_ID_REF
---------- -----------
        51             
        52          51 
        53             
        54             
        55             
        56             
        57             
        58             
        59             
        60             
        61             
        62             
        81             
        82          61 
        83             
        84
```

--

```
WITH RSFC(A,B,LVL) AS 
  (SELECT CMPI_CODE,CMPI_ID_REF,0 AS LVL FROM del R where CMPI_ID_REF is null
  UNION ALL SELECT A,B,LVL+1 FROM RSFC R
  INNER JOIN DEL F ON R.A = F.CMPI_ID_REF
  ) 
  select * from rsfc
```

This like is showing error `SQL Error: ORA-32044: cycle detected while executing recursive WITH query`

Comment: Can you set up a SQL Fiddle showing this error?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5f3b40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be selecting the wrong value in the recursive member. Looking at just the first two rows, the anchor member would get `A, B, LVL` as `51, null, 0`. The first recursive member would use `51` to get the second row; but you're select `A, B, LVL+1`, so that would get `51, null, 1`. Then the next one would get the same... hence the loop. So you need to select:

```
  UNION ALL SELECT F.CMPI_CODE,CMPI_ID_REF,LVL+1 FROM RSFC R
  INNER JOIN DEL F ON R.A = F.CMPI_ID_REF
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5f3b40/6) based on yours. Not sure if that's the final result you want though.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Oracle does not do hierarchical queries using the same syntax as Sql server and WITH keyword is intended to different uses.</strike>

to do a hierarchical query use the following query:

```
SELECT DEL.*, level as LVL
FROM
    DEL 
CONNECT BY PRIOR
    CMPI_CODE = CMPI_ID_REF
START WITH
    CMPI_ID_REF IS NULL;
```

Comment: Oracle *does* support recursive CTEs since version 11.2 (and btw: recursive CTEs and the `WITH` keyword is nothing special to SQL Server, it's defined by the SQL standard and many modern DBMS support that)

Comment: And the error message received seems to explicitly allow recursive queries (but disallows infinite loops for obvious reasons).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Oh didn't know that, it seems my experience with Oracle is a bit outdated, anyways, my query is a suggestion to a different approach of solving things.